# Loop - removing elements from array

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to remove specific elements from an array that is found in another array. My array is returning unchanged. My assumption is my condition in the `if` statement is not correct, however, I can't find a clear explanation online as to what this is supposed to be exactly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Trying to remove `...args` from `array`

````
    <script>
        removeFromArray = function(array, ...args) {

            let removalItems = Array.from(args);

            for (i = 0; i < removalItems.length; i++) {
                if (array === removalItems[i]) {
                    array.splice(i, 1);
                } else {
                    i++
                }
            }
            // console.log(array);
            return array;
        }
        removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2)
    </script>
    ```
````

Comment: assuming array is an array how do you expect array === removalItems[i] to work?  you need  nested for loops

Comment: if (array === removalItems[i]) , how is it at all possible?

Comment: array is a different array from removalItems[i].  array = [1, 2, 3, 4] while removalItems = [3,2]

Comment: there are some method for array iteration you can try each of them https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_iteration.asp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are treating array as if it has single object.

1. Loop over the array and using includes method check if that element if present in the removalItems array . If yes splice , else increment.

```js
removeFromArray = function(array, ...args) {

            let removalItems = Array.from(args);
            for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (removalItems.includes(array[i])) {
                    array.splice(i, 1);
                 i--;
                } 
            }
            // console.log(array);
            return array;
        }
        console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2));
```

Here is the another solution , without splicing the array while iterating over it.

```js
removeFromArray = function(array, ...args) {

            let removalItems = Array.from(args);
            let result = [];
            for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (!removalItems.includes(array[i])) {
                    result.push(array[i]);
                } 
            }
            // console.log(array);
            return result;
        }
        console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2));
```

Comment: the else part would skip every second item

Comment: Splicing the array you are iterating is a really bad practice

Comment: @charlietfl I have added the another solution also considering splicing while iterating as bad practice. Thank you for sharing the information!

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that you are making one loop through `removeFromArray` but you are not looping through your array to check every element in array against removefromarray you have to use nested loop

```js
removeFromArray = function(array, ...args) {

            let removalItems = Array.from(args);

            for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
              for (j = 0; j < removalItems.length; j++) {
                if (array[i] === removalItems[j]) {
                    array.splice(i, 1);
                    i--
                } 
                else continue
            }
        }
        return array
      }
        
        console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2))
```

A different approach is to use filter

```js
removeFromArray = function(array, ...args) {
        let removalItems = Array.from(args);
       return array.filter(x=>!removalItems.some(y=>x==y))
    }
    console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `filter()` would simplify this and would not mutate original array

```js
const removeFromArray = (array, ...args) => {
  let removalItems = new Set(args);
  return array.filter(e => !removalItems.has(e));
}
console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have few errors, wont work if they are not in same position and also as you remove the item with slice you need to decrement i otherwise you will skip items

```
const removeFromArray = (array, ...removalItems) => {
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (removalItems.includes(array[i])) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

But filter is much clenaner

```
const removeFromArray = (array, ...removalItems) => array.filter(x => !removalItems.includes(x))
```

Answer (score -1):

In your for loop you have to

```
for (let j=0; j<array.length; j++)
    if (array[j]===removalItems[i])
        ...the rest is the same
```

Comment: index of `removalItems` should never be relevant for OP's objective

Answer (score -1):

Using your same code pattern, you have 3 mistakes:

```
        let removalItems = Array.from(args);

        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
           for (j = 0; j < removalItems.length; j++) {
              if (array[i] === removalItems[j]) {
                  array.splice(i, 1);
                  i--
              }
           }
        }
```

Furthermore you need another for loop to iterate through all the options.
This code has ended up being slightly inefficient but it'll do for most applications. I removed the else statement because you are already incrememnting i every time you loop.

Comment: What mistakes did I make? I don't see it in your reply.

Comment: `array.length` instead of `removalItems.length` and `array[i]` in the `if` statement

Comment: You need to check `removalItems` on an independent index, not on `removalItems[i]`.

Comment: Unless you also decrement `i` when splicing this will fail. That is why splicing array being iterated is bad practice. Or work from end of array to start so length change won't affect loop